# Having Trouble Decomposing This Partial Fraction

Tags: partial-fractions

1/(s^2)((s-3)^2)

I'm having trouble decomposing this particular fraction.
Wolfram won't help, and other forums only suggest to use a CAS program.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Write
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{s^2(s-3)^2} = \frac{A}{s}+\frac{B}{s^2} + \frac{C}{(s-3)} + \frac{D}{(s-3)^2}
\end{align}
and solve for $A, B, C$ and $D$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$\frac{1}{s(s-3)} = \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{s-3}-\frac{1}{s}\right)$$

Use this twice to decompose: $$\frac{1}{s^2(s-3)^2} = \left(\frac{1}{s(s-3)} \right)^2$$

Comment: Very cute. (+1)

Comment: @JackyChong Thanks. Math is one of few places where lazy shortcuts may be considered *cute* ;-)